# irritated vs annoyed

Tags: meaning, differences

When trying to understand the difference between irritated and annoyed I get this definition:

Annoy means: To disturb or **irritate**, especially by continued or repeated acts; to bother with unpleasant deeds. Are they kidding? Annoy means irritate? What is that?

Then how to get the difference? Please help to understand.

Comment: Whether you like it or not, they are synonyms. Guess what the definition of "irritate" will say! But if you check [this link](https://diffsense.com/diff/annoy/irritate#:~:text=The%20difference%20between%20Annoy%20and,%2C%20anger%2C%20or%20displeasure%20in.) maybe the difference will be clear to you.

Comment: No, of course they are not kidding. English has many pairs of words with very similar meanings. You might be _annoyed_ with someone because they have deliberately done something that inconvenienced you; you might be _irritated_ because they keep coughing, even though you know they can't help it.

Comment: They're not synonyms. _Irritate_ refers to a physical effect produced by something outside whatever gets irritated. _Annoy_, on the other hand, is non-physical (your eye can get irritated, but not annoyed, for instance) and refers directly and only to emotions. _Irritation_ is always metaphoric when it refers to emotions; the image is of a wounded, steaming, brain.

Comment: @JohnLawler: [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/annoyed.html) says they are synonyms. I did not say they were perfect synonyms.

Comment: It's hard to help with hypothetical problems. Give us a few examples where you think each one fits.

Comment: @JohnLawler I recommend making this an answer (aside from the comment about whether/not they're synonyms)

Comment: Nah, I don't have an image  to display. Plus you can always understand it as a comment, even if it isn't official.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The words are sometimes synonymous. Let's look at other words that are associated with *annoy* and *irritate* in dictionaries.

I have taken the key words from Cambridge, Merriam Webster and Collins. Rather than bore you with a list of tedious definitions, this is what I find in my Venn diagram:

The synonymous area is central and orange. *Irritate* in the pink area is additionally associated with soreness (physical, but could be mental by analogy). *Annoy* is additionally associated with the words in the yellow area on the right.

I suggest that a focus on the central area produces reasonable claims of synonymy but that there are also differences of meaning shown by the pink and yellow areas. These differences may be brought out in various contexts.

[image]

Comment: Well done. A good answer well demonstrated.

Comment: @Greybeard Kind of you. Thank you. I sometimes think set theory could be used more in the examination of meanings but I am too often easily diverted by pleasures of the language itself.

Comment: Such a perfect illustration! Thank you!